# CoffeeScript require("foo") vs require "foo"

Tags: coffeescript

What is the different between

```
myFoo = require("foo")
# versus
myFoo = require "foo"
```

In coffeescript.

Comment: You can compile both fragments and compare the resulting javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference (beyond code style): They result in the exact same Javascript code:

```
var myFoo;

myFoo = require("foo");
```